# Comparing Two Arrays ActionScript 3

Tags: arrays, actionscript, compare

Let's say I have two arrays:

```
var arrOne:Array = ["fish", "cat", "dog", "tree", "frog"];
var arrTwo:Array = ["cat", "cat", "fish", "dog", "fish"];
```

I need to be able to compare them to determine the following:

- How many matching items there are in the same position (in the case above there would be 1: arrOne[1] and arrTwo[1] are both cat).
- How many matches there are that are not in the same position (in this case above there would be 2: cat and fish).

This will be comparing a user's input to a randomly generated array of values; basically I want to be able to say "You got one correct and in the right spot, and two correct but in the wrong spot". Hopefully this makes sense. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What about "dog" for the second situation?

Answer (score 0):

I would just compare the elements in the common way. The only problem is how we should treat the "fish" for the second situation.

Here is my solution for two cases. 1 - if we don't care about repeated items, 2 - if we do.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        private var arrOne:Array = ["fish", "cat", "dog", "tree", "frog"];
        private var arrTwo:Array = ["cat", "cat", "fish", "dog", "fish"];

        protected function compare():void
        {
            var rule1:int = 0;
            var rule2:int = 0;

            for (var i: int = 0; i < arrOne.length; i++)
            {
                for (var j: int = 0; j < arrTwo.length; j++)
                {
                    if (arrOne[i] == arrTwo[j])
                    {
                        if (i == j)
                            rule1 ++;
                        else
                            rule2 ++;
                    }
                }
            }

            Alert.show("You got " + rule1.toString() + " correct and in the right spot, and " + rule2.toString() + " correct but in the wrong spot");

        }

        protected function compareWithoutRepeat():void
        {
            var rule1:int = 0;
            var rule2:int = 0;
            var temp:Array = new Array();

            for (var i: int = 0; i < arrOne.length; i++)
            {
                for (var j: int = 0; j < arrTwo.length; j++)
                {
                    if (arrOne[i] == arrTwo[j])
                    {
                        if (i == j)
                            rule1 ++;
                        else
                        {
                            var flag:Boolean = false; //is there the same word in the past?
                            for (var k:int = 0; k < temp.length; k++)
                            {
                                if (temp[k] == arrTwo[j])
                                {
                                    flag = true;
                                    break;
                                }

                            }

                            if (!flag) //the word is new, count it!
                            {
                                rule2 ++;
                                temp.push(arrTwo[j]);
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            Alert.show("You got " + rule1.toString() + " correct and in the right spot, and " + rule2.toString() + " correct but in the wrong spot");

        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:Button x="10" y="10" width="153" label="Compare" click="compare()"/>
<s:Button x="10" y="39" label="Compare without repeat" click="compareWithoutRepeat()"/>
</s:Application>
```